# Set Canvas to Eclipse View?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've created an (empty until now) View in my Eclipse Plugin. I'm also using [Eclipse Cloudio](https://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF/GEF4/Cloudio). This library provides the following object (description taken from the linked site):

> A TagCloud is a special org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas, dedicated to display a tag cloud.

Basically it's an image showing a WordCloud. Now there are snippets on the site on how to  show such TagClouds in a shell / popup.

But I'd like to show them in a view (this function is supposed to be used often and I think it's bad style to spam popup-windows).

What I do not know tho is how to set this TagCloud (which is a Canvas) to the View / make the View display the Canvas. Maybe someone can help me with this?

Edit:
gregs Answer works like a charm! It just needs another setWords() function which is called from where-ever which contains .setWords to set the words when neccessary.

Comment: Did you read the [Creating an Eclipse View](https://eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html) article? Though it is old, the core concepts are still valid (just ignore _Step1_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the control to the view in the view `createPartControl`. At the simplest that would be:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
{
  TagCloud cloud = new TagCloud(parent, SWT.NONE);

  ... set up the cloud as in the example
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, that sounds reasonable. Is there any way to trigger that function after startup? There is no data to fill at startup, but it's supposed to trigger when this data occurs.

Comment: No, this is only run when the view is created. You can presumably set data in the control later on.